# Objective-C change image color performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am currently using the function below to change png image color, the color is set through a color slider, so while sliding through colors everything works fine and get the resulted image colored correspondingly, I am only having issue with slider performance while sliding, it keeps lagging as well as for the image color update, need help to make the process smooth.

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage fixedHue:(CGFloat)hue saturation:(CGFloat)saturation brightness:(CGFloat)brightness alpha:(CGFloat)alpha{
    CGSize imageSize = [sourceImage size];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, sourceImage.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, sourceImage.size.width, sourceImage.size.height);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, sourceImage.CGImage);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeColor);
    [[UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:alpha] setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDestinationIn);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, sourceImage.CGImage);
    CGContextFlush(context);
    UIImage *editedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return editedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an async version of your function as follows...

```
- (void)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage
              fixedHue:(CGFloat)hue
            saturation:(CGFloat)saturation
            brightness:(CGFloat)brightness
                 alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
            completion:(void (^)(UIImage *))completion {

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        // call your original function.  Use this to create the context...
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, YES, 0.0 );
        // don't call CGContextFillRect, call...
        UIRectFill(rect);
        // don't call CGContextDrawImage, call...
        [sourceImage drawInRect:rect]
        // don't call CGContextFlush, don't need to replace that

        UIImage *image = [self imageWithImage:sourceImage fixedHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:alpha];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completion(image);
        });
    });
}
```

Use it like this:

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    [self imageWithImage:sourceImage
                fixedHue:hue
              saturation:saturation
              brightness:brightness
                   alpha:alpha
              completion:^(UIImage *image) {
                  // update the UI here with image
              }]; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Danh, the app crashes on this line
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
says should be implemented on UI thread, did add this line to dispatch on main thread still no luck

Comment: Ah - sorry.  Don't get the current context.  Create one.  Will post an edit in a few mins.

Comment: Sorry - I only just now read your original code carefully.   You are created a CGContext, and I think I've found all the changes you need to run off the main (off the main,  UI actions are prohibited).